# facebook sdk: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user"

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-access-token

When I try to query facebook, I get the following exception:
"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

This is the request:

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    accessToken,
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            FacebookRequestError responseError = response.getError();
                            if(responseError != null){
                                if(responseError.getCategory().equals(FacebookRequestError.Category.LOGIN_RECOVERABLE)){
                                    LoginManager.getInstance().resolveError(MainActivity.this, response);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.facebookError), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    Log.e(TAG, Helper.isFacebookLogin() + "");
                                    return;
                                }
                            } else {
                                try {
                                    Log.e(TAG + " newMeRequest id", object.getString("id"));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG + " newMeRequest JSONerror", e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }


                        }

                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,gender");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            reques

t.executeAsync();
```

Helper.isFacebookLogin() is:

```
public static boolean isFacebookLogin(){
    return accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();
}
```

and returns `true`.

If it returns true, why do I get the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code, this code has been widely tested with the  multiple boundary conditions & used multiple times:

```
//on click of fb button
        private void handleFBLogin() {
                AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(ActivityLogin.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
                LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        setFacebookData(loginResult, d);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Canceled login ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                                d.dismiss();
                                if (exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) {
                                    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                                        handleFBLogin();
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR " + exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show();

                                PackageInfo info;
                                try {
                                    info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo([your package name], PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                                    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                                        MessageDigest md;
                                        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                                        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                                        String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                                        //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
                                        Log.e("hash key", something);
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e1) {
                                    Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }


    private void setFacebookData(final LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                                final String firstName = response.getJSONObject().getString("first_name");
                                String lastName = response.getJSONObject().getString("last_name");
                                String id = response.getJSONObject().getString("id");
                                String email = null;
                                if (response.getJSONObject().has("email"))
                                    email = response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                                //put your code here
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,first_name,last_name,gender");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Nothing in this post helped me. I still get the same error message.